# How to unit test a model with foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, unit-testing, go, go-gorm

I'm writing unit tests with database in Go.

My models have several layers and it's like *Tour* has a many-to-many relationship with *Collect* and *Collect* has a many-to-many relationship with *Song* too.

How do I write such tests and generate test cases efficiently? I'm using go-sqlmock to mock queries, however, since that models have foreign keys so that I need to generate at least 3 mock queries for a single test case.

I've studied [table-driven tests](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests) that official recommends, however, I think it's much harder for my cases.

Below are some code for your information.

```golang
type Tour struct {
    gorm.Model `json:"-"`
    Collects   []*Collect `gorm:"many2many:tour_collects;" json:"collects"`
}
type Collect struct {
    gorm.Model `json:"-"`
    Title      string  `json:"title"`
    Songs      []*Song `gorm:"many2many:collect_songs;" json:"songs"`
    FrontendID uint    `json:"id"`
}
func GetTour(id int) (*Tour, error) {
    var tour Tour
    err := db.Preload("Collects").Where("id = ?", id).First(&tour).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &tour, nil
}
func TestGetTourSuccess(t *testing.T) {
    mock := setupTestDatabase(t)
    if mock == nil {
        return
    }

    mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT (.+) FROM `tours` WHERE (.+) AND `tours`.`deleted_at` IS NULL ORDER BY `tours`.`id` LIMIT 1").
        WithArgs(1).
        WillReturnRows(
            sqlmock.NewRows(tourColumns).AddRow(1, time.Now(), time.Now(), nil),
        )
    mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT (.+) FROM `tour_collects` WHERE `tour_collects`.`tour_id` = \\?").
        WithArgs(1).WillReturnRows(
        sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"tour_id", "collect_id"}).AddRow(1, 1).AddRow(1, 2).AddRow(1, 3),
    )
    mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT (.+) FROM `collects`").WithArgs(testCollectID...).WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows(collectColumns).
        AddRow(1, time.Now(), time.Now(), nil, "hello").
        AddRow(2, time.Now(), time.Now(), nil, "world").
        AddRow(3, time.Now(), time.Now(), nil, "hi"))
    tour, err := GetTour(1)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("errors happened when get tour: ", err.Error())
    }

    if tour.ID != 1 {
        t.Error("error that tour id is not matched")
    }

    for i := range tour.Collects {
        if v := testCollectID[i].(int); v != int(tour.Collects[i].ID) {
            t.Error("collect id is not matched", v, int(tour.Collects[i].ID))
        }
    }
    if err := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); err != nil {
        t.Error("errors that expectations were not met: ", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: Foreign keys or not don't change your testing approach. If you find it's over complex to test a function, you're probably testing too big of a unit.

Comment: Also, why are you doing multiple queries for FK relationships, rather than using JOINs?

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks for reply, I've updated code with *GetTour*. I use gorm to interact with db, and with preload, it generate 3 queries when run *GetTour*. Do I need to switch to raw SQL for elasticity and testable code?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. In [_my personal opinion_](https://jhall.io/posts/my-controversial-opinions/#1-orms-object-relational-mappers-are-terrible), ORMs like GORM are terrible, and should never be used, not just because they make testing a pain, but because they make everything a pain.  But that's not a popular opinion.